# Possible server side Video streaming issue

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video, jwplayer, rtmp

Please attempt to view these two video streams

http://www.streaming.co.uk/sam/JWplayer_prototype/basic.htm
http://www.streaming.co.uk/sam/JWplayer_prototype/related_videos.htm

Both used to work
But they now say file not found within the player

I suspect this is a server issue since I used one browser on my machine before they stopped working and this browser will still play both streams but my others browsers will not (suggesting that the one browser which works is playing a cached version)

please 
1) State if or not they work for you
2) have a look at the source codes for each and tell me if you spot any syntactical errors which could cause this.

Thanks

Comment: Seems sketchy... oh well, clear your cache to find out if it's actually working or not!

Answer (score 1):

I can see at least 3 things that will give you cross-browser headaches:

- The media file is an MP4, these are not supported by FireFox due to patents.
- The protocol used to fetch the file is rtmp which may have limited browser support
- The media file is hosted on a different domain, which might give you cross-domain security policy restrictions.